# Setting bar colors in Vaadin Charts for ListSeries (on BasicColumn)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-charts

Using Vaadin 6.x and Vaadin Charts, I am playing around with BasicColumn (http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#BasicColumn). 
I want the user to choose bar column colors on the screen. I correctly get the color from user however I couldn't manage to set colors of the column bars dynamically.

I know it is pretty simple with DataSeriesItem however there is no color attribute for ListSeries.

Is there a way to set the colors of bars on BasicColumn?

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation for DataSeries.  But as you set the color on PlotOptionsColumn it should as well work for ListSeries:

```
        pingDropoutSr=new DataSeries();
        PlotOptionsColumn dropOptions= new PlotOptionsColumn();
        dropOptions.setColor( SolidColor.GREEN ); //Color is an interface only
        pingDropoutSr.setPlotOptions(dropOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718729/set-or-get-color-for-listseries-in-vaadin-charts/39725215#39725215), and found a solution using **PlotOptionsColumn**.

```
//Hard Coded Values
String months[] = { "DataSet 1", "DataSet 2", "DataSet 3", "DataSet 4", "DataSet 5"};

int dataArray[][] = { 
        { 8, 13, 7, 4 }, 
        { 23, 1, 30, 7 },
        { 37, 3, 22, 2 },
        { 13, 23, 4, 3 },
        { 3, 10, 9, 5 },
};

int counter = 0;

// Data series for each numeric column in the table
for (int month = 0; month < 4; month++) {

    ListSeries series = new ListSeries();
    PlotOptionsColumn options = new PlotOptionsColumn();
    options.setColor(colors[counter++]);
    series.setPlotOptions(options);
    series.setName(months[month]);

    // The rows of the table
    for (int data = 0; data < dataArray.length; data++) {
        series.addData(dataArray[data][month]);
    }

    conf.addSeries(series);
}
```